# Donation report by exception

Tags: donations

Is there a report available in CiviCRM to show list of donors with or without tax receipts issued instead of viewing each donor one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, under Reports - Contribution Reports, choose New Contribution Report. Then there are choices for Not Issued and Issued. You can then choose some options and Save that report for future use.

(Based on your other questions I assume by "tax receipt" you mean "CDN Tax Receipt" from the CDN Tax Receipts extension.)